# "Error in plot.xy(xy.coords(x, y), type = type, ...) : plot.new has not been called yet"

Tags: r

Some unsual error appears with line function in R, when I want line

```
lines(soy$Year,ci_soy[,1],col='black',lwd=3)

lines(soy$Year,ci_soy[,1],type="l", col="green", lwd=3,xlab="Year", ylab="bu_acre")

plot(soy$Year,ci_soy[,1],type="l", col="green", lwd=3,xlab="Year", ylab="bu_acre")
```

[image]

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution should be: First call this line of your code

`plot(mtcars$disp,ci_mtcars[,1],type="l", col="green", lwd=3,xlab="disp", ylab="bu_acre")`

Explanation: In base R first you have to start a plot with `plot` to generate a plot. In this plot then your `lines` function can be added. See my example:

```
# without plot

lines(iris$Sepal.Length, col='black',lwd=3)

Output:
error in plot.xy(xy.coords(x, y), type = type, ...) : 
  plot.new has not been called yet

# with plot

# empty plot frame for lines
plot(1, type="n", xlab="", ylab="", xlim=c(0, 100), ylim=c(0, 10))
lines(iris$Sepal.Length, col='black',lwd=3)
```

output:
[image]